# Azure Vault Running Locally

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, encryption, azure-keyvault

My project does not have access to the real azure repos. However, with regards to Storage and Tables, i am able to manage that by running locally and also mapping my settings to point to my local dev storage. So whatever i do, it gets saved in my Blobs/Tables which i can see in the Azure Storage Explorer.

However, is there anyways, we can do the same with Azure Vault ?
I do not see any Vault related stuff in the azure storage explorer.
Is there a local explorer that can achieve this?

The error i receive is mainly when i try to insert in the sql server as the columns are encrypted.
"Error: 'Could not insert policy card details [Failed to decrypt a column encryption key using key store provider: 'AZURE_KEY_VAULT'. Verify the properties of the column encryption key and its column master key in your database. The last 10 bytes of the encrypted column encryption key are: 'E8-B6-6E-65-D4-A3-0E-01-EE-9C'.\r\nOne or more errors occurred. (Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden')]'"

So ideally, i want to configure the Vault locally, How do i go about doing this?

Thanks
Shank

Comment: There is no emulator for keyvault. You need an actual one on azure

Comment: AKV runs on Azure Stack Hub https://azure.microsoft.com/en-ca/products/azure-stack/hub/

Comment: This is typical microsoft, not providing emulators for their services. Thats really bad, so you are dependent on them all the time.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether you have solved this issue or not, but wanted to chime in just in case it will help someone.

It is not guaranteed to work as this is a very much unofficial project, but you could try using Lowkey Vault for local Key Vault use-cases. It is a test double (fake) for Azure Key Vault that (at the time of writing) supports key and secret APIs for the v7.2 REST API (and partially v7.3 too).

It can be found here, in case you wanted to try your luck with it: https://github.com/nagyesta/lowkey-vault